# $\mathbb{Q}$ do not have LUB but enjoys Archimedian Property

Tags: real-analysis

How can we proof archimedian property of $\mathbb{Q}$. In $\mathbb{R}$ we used LUB to prove it. But since in $\mathbb{Q}$ we do not have LUB how can we prove it?

Answer (score 3):

It's straightforward. If $a/b>0$ and $c/d>0$ with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb N$, then
$$
\frac cd< (bc+1)\,\frac ab.
$$